# Second macro in Excel doesn't run

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

my problem is kind of odd... I have code in Access VBA. There I want to run two macros in other Excel file. First macro run with no problem, but when dubbger get second, I'm given a Run-time error 1004: "Cannot run the macro 'prcPrepareFirstReport'. The macro not be available in this worbook or all macros be disabled."

The code of Access:

```
Private Sub cmdRaport_Click()
    Dim pPath As String            
    Dim pWorkPath As String        
    Dim pExcel As Object
    Dim pPathToSave As String
    Dim pTargetPath As String

    pPath = fncFilePicker()

    pWorkPath = DLookup("[F_LINK]", "tblLinks", "[F_ID] = 1")
    Set pExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    pExcel.Workbooks.Open (pWorkPath)
    pMacro = "prcPrepareFile"

    pPathToSave = DLookup("[F_LINK]", "tblLinks", "[F_ID] = 2")

    pExcel.Run pMacro, pPath, pPathToSave 'this macro is going fine

    pMacro = "prcPrepareFirstReport"

    pTargetPath = DLookup("[F_LINK]", "tblLinks", "[F_ID] = 5")

    pExcel.Run pMacro, pTargetPath 'on this macro I'm given error 1004

    pExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    pExcel.Quit

    Set pExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Excel VBA code:

```
Public pSourceName As String
Sub prcPrepareFile(pPath As String, pPathToSave As String)
    Dim pFileToPrepare As Workbook
    Dim pSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pLastRow As Long        
    Dim pName As String 
    Dim i As Long

    With Application
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set pFileToPrepare = Workbooks.Open(pPath)

    Set pSheet = pFileToPrepare.Worksheets(1)

    pSheet.Rows("1:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    pSheet.Rows("2:5").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    pLastRow = pSheet.Cells(pSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To pLastRow
        If pSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
           pSheet.Rows(i & ":" & i + 5).Select
           Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

    pName = pFileToPrepare.Name
    pName = pPathToSave & pName
    Debug.Print pName
    pFileToPrepare.SaveAs pName

    pSourceName = pFileToPrepare.Name

    With Application
       .DisplayAlerts = True
       .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub prcPrepareFirstReport(pTargetPath As String)
    Dim pSourceWorbook As Workbook
    Dim pTargetWorkbook As Workbook

    Set pSourceWorbook = Workbooks(pSourceName)
    Set pTargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(pTargetPath)
End Sub
```

I've tried version such

```
pExcel.Application.Run pMacro
```

, but it's not working...

I've tried to run only this second macro and it's on...

Please help.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have defined pTargetPath in the first code (`Dim pTargetPath as String`). Does adding that make any difference?

Comment: Is `prcPrepareFile` saving the workbook as an `xlsx` file?

Comment: @finjo, sorry I forget to type it. In normal code it is.

Comment: @Comintern Yes, but other file, not this one where code is.

Comment: Can you post the code for that `Sub` then?  I suspect that's where the issue is.

Comment: Which workbook and module is the `prcPrepareFirstReport` code in?

Comment: @Comintern I added it in post. There are also public variable above sub.

Comment: @Rory the same workbook and module as prcPrepareFile

Comment: What is the name of the module? Ideally you should prefix the call with the name of the workbook: `Run 'workbook_name'!macro_name`

Comment: @Rory Module1 . I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this up. Help from @Comintern and @Rory was essential:)

So the problem was, that after run `prcPrepareFile` the other Excel was activate, not this with macro code. I don't know why (maybe someone could it explains), but after it the variable `pExcel` had in it this second Excel without VBA code...

The solution is to prepare variable with name of this first Excel and then run this second macro with name of this first Excel. The right code below:

```
Dim pSourceName As String
Dim pWorkWorkbookName As String

pWorkWorkbookName = pExcel.Names.Parent.Name
pSourceName = pExcel.Run(pMacro, pPath, pPathToSave)

pMacro = "prcPrepareFirstReport"

pTargetPath = DLookup("[F_LINK]", "tblLinks", "[F_ID] = 5")

pExcel.Run "'" & pWorkWorkbookName & "'!" & pMacro, pTargetPath, pSourceName
```

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your public variable `pSourceName` is losing state between the two calls to `Application.Run` in the calling code. A much more robust solution than using a global state variable is to convert `prcPrepareFile` to a function that returns the `pSourceName`, then pass *that* to `prcPrepareFirstReport`.

**Excel code:**

```
Public Function prcPrepareFile(pPath As String, pPathToSave As String) As String
    'Snip
    pName = pFileToPrepare.Name
    pName = pPathToSave & pName
    pFileToPrepare.SaveAs pName

    prcPrepareFile = pFileToPrepare.Name
    With Application
       .DisplayAlerts = True
       .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Function

Sub prcPrepareFirstReport(pTargetPath As String, pSourceName As String)
    Dim pSourceWorbook As Workbook
    Dim pTargetWorkbook As Workbook

    Set pSourceWorbook = Workbooks(pSourceName)
    Set pTargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(pTargetPath)
End Sub
```

**Calling code:**

```
Dim pSourceName As String
pSourceName = pExcel.Run(pMacro, pPath, pPathToSave)

pMacro = "prcPrepareFirstReport"

pTargetPath = DLookup("[F_LINK]", "tblLinks", "[F_ID] = 5")

pExcel.Run pMacro, pTargetPath, pSourceName
```

Comment: I got the same error. I noticed something weird. After run this first macro, the pExcel was no this Excel that I runed. `pExcel.Name` is now H:\DATA\Microsoft Excel.xlsx.